# How to make Mac OS as a slave in JMETER distributed testing

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

I am using Jmeter to perform  distributed stress testing. I have 5 Mac and 2 window machines in my Lab. I tried Mac as Master and window machines as slave and was successful but i want to USE only Mac machines to perform this testing. How can i make MAC as a slave. I have gone through many forums but found only discussions about LINUX and Window. In Linux they have mentioned to run jmeter-server file.How can i Perform the same in Mac.

Thanks
Rajneesh

Comment: Oliver is right OSX should be the same as linux. I assume you saw this? http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf if yes with exactly what part you're having issues?

Answer (score 2):

OSX is Unix based, the same as Linux. Just open Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities) and perform the same operations as you would for Linux.